# best solution to share a function in many components in angular

Tags: angular

I need a function shared in two component, I think that we can put this function in service or use a custom pipe if we use this function in template but what's the best solution ?

Comment: Depends on what the function does.

Comment: a custom pipe is a pipe. Do you want a pipe, or a function that you can call from the TypeScript code of your two components? Do you know what a pipe is and what they're used for? Does your function qualify? What is it supposed to do and here do you plan to use it?

Comment: it's just a function that check if the string is a palindrom or not. I need to call this method in two component

Comment: Maybe you should show the function in question and a sample of how it will be used.

Comment: Then you should probably use neither of those. Just a function exported from a TypeScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), this is how they introduce pipes:

> Introducing Angular pipes, a way to write display-value transformations that you can declare in your HTML.

Functions, accessed via a service or not, are available for any form of processing, access APIs, do complex processing, etc. If you need some processing done across several components then placing the function in a service isn't a bad idea.

Pipes are good for when you need to format some data (a date, do some string processing before injecting to the HTML, etc) and can easily be included in multiple pages.

So, decide what your intention is and use the correct component to achieve the goal. If you want to alter or edit how something appears in HTML a pipe is probably what you want.

If it is complex, non-trivial or has no display effect on the HTML then a function is the appropriate choice.

Option three is to simply create another file that holds this function (and any other utility/helper style functions you need) and import that as required.

Comment: I want to check in first component if the word is palindrome then idisplay ok in html otherwise ko, second component will display a list of palindone via API and will display valid palindrome lines in green and invalid in red

Comment: A pipe would easily work, or a helper file of useful functions. A service is going too far if that palindrome is all it is going to do.

Comment: so you advise me to use a helper file of useful functions or a pipe

Answer (score 0):

If the function has state or dependencies, then a service is best.

Otherwise, I've gone with just a simple [business-area].utility.ts file and stuck all of my pure functions there.